# IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я понимаю смысл ошибки, но не понимаю причины ее возникновения:

```
missionItems = new MissionItem[50];
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        missionItems[i] = Instantiate(missionItem);  
        missionItems[i].transform.GetChild(2).GetChild(1).GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => ClickPrize(missionItems[i]));
    }
```

Ошибка ругается на `AddListener(() => ClickPrize(missionItems[i]))` , но не понимаю, как тут может выходить за границы, если создается при заполнении массива.

P.S. Ошибка возникает только при нажатии на кнопку, а не при создании.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В цикле `for` необходимо создавать переменную `index`, а затем присвоить ей `i`. Сейчас у вас в лямбду захватывается `i`, в итоге получается, когда нажимаете кнопку, вызывается `ClickPrize(missionItems[50])`, так как `i = 50` в конце цикла.

Отредактируйте ваш код следующим образом:

```
    missionItems = new MissionItem[50];
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        var index = i;
        missionItems[i] = Instantiate(missionItem);  
        missionItems[i].transform.GetChild(2).GetChild(1).GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => ClickPrize(missionItems[index]));
    }
```

Comment: блин, точно, недавно же статью об этом читал